# add Seconds to a date and get new date

Tags: c#

How to Get new Date provided a date and number of seconds passed from that date.For Example                03-12-2014 12:30:02 AM is the date and 124 are the seconds lapsed then new date time should be  03-12-2014 12:32:06 AM

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
string strDate = "03-12-2014 12:30:02 AM ";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(strDate , out date))
{
    date = date.AddSeconds(124);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use addition operator with a `TimeSpan`:

```
var date = myDate + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(124);
```